# Parameter 0 of constructor in AuthService required a bean of type 'springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Below you will find the 2 classes that I think you guys need. If any more info is required please let me know.
AuthService

```
package com.r.reservationproject.services;

import com.r.reservationproject.dto.AuthenticationResponse;
import com.r.reservationproject.dto.RegisterRequest;
import com.r.reservationproject.domain.NotificationEmail;
import com.r.reservationproject.domain.User;
import com.r.reservationproject.domain.VerificationToken;
import com.r.reservationproject.dto.LoginRequest;
import com.r.reservationproject.exceptions.SpringReservationAccountException;
import com.r.reservationproject.repositories.UserRepo;
import com.r.reservationproject.repositories.VerificationTokenRepo;
import com.r.reservationproject.security.JwtProvider;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Transactional
// Contains logic to create username password authentication token and use authenticationManager to perform login
public class AuthService {
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    private final VerificationTokenRepo verificationTokenRepo;
    private final MailService mailService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    public void signup(RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(registerRequest.getUsername());
        user.setEmail(registerRequest.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()));
        user.setCreated(Instant.now());
        user.setEnabled(false);

        userRepo.save(user);

        String token = generateVerificationToken(user);
        mailService.sendMail(new NotificationEmail("Activeren account applicatie", user.getEmail(),
                "Bedankt voor het gebruiken van onze applicatie, om uw account te activeren vragen wij u om volgende link te klikken :" +
                        "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/accountVerification/" + token));
    }

    private String generateVerificationToken(User user) {
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        VerificationToken verificationToken = new VerificationToken();
        verificationToken.setToken(token);
        verificationToken.setUser(user);

        verificationTokenRepo.save(verificationToken);
        return token;
    }

    public void verifyAccount(String token) {
        Optional<VerificationToken> verificationToken =  verificationTokenRepo.findByToken(token);
        verificationToken.orElseThrow(() -> new SpringReservationAccountException("Token is niet geldig"));
        fetchUserAndEnable(verificationToken.get());
    }

    public void fetchUserAndEnable(VerificationToken verificationToken) {
        @NotBlank(message = "Username is required") String username = verificationToken.getUser().getUsername();
        User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new SpringReservationAccountException("Gebruiker onbekend"));
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepo.save(user);
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
        String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(authenticate);
        // to send this token we use a dto (authenticationresponse)
        return new AuthenticationResponse(token, loginRequest.getUsername());

    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
package com.r.reservationproject.config;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Full error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.r.reservationproject.services.AuthService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.

I don't get the error since I already defined the Bean in the SecurityConfig

I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: have you tried to declaring that bean in scope public, instead of package?

Comment: @Stultuske I'm pretty new to this so it would be helpful to know how to do it :)

Comment: by putting the keyword 'public' in front of 'PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()' just as you do with the other Beans. If you don't know how to do this, you should start with learning the basics instead of trying on advanced frameworks like Spring

Comment: Oh of course I already tried that, I wasn't sure what you meant

Comment: I'm new to Spring, not Java ;)

Comment: the class in which you declare that bean is not configured to declare them. add the @Configuration annotation to the class

Comment: Ah thanks I forgot that indeed, but still same error

Comment: have you tried autowiring the fields, instead of relying on lombok?

Comment: I did try this for the AuthService's private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
But it gave me the message : Could not autowire. No beans of 'PasswordEncoder' type found. This just doesn't make any sense for me.

Comment: Add `@Configuration` annotation to your `SecurityConfig` class to let Spring know there are some bean definitions there

Comment: as javadoc to `@EnableWebSecurity` suggests, *"Add this annotation to an @Configuration class to have the Spring Security configuration defined in any WebSecurityConfigurer or more likely by exposing a SecurityFilterChain bean:"*

Comment: A comment about the use of lombok, the best way is to use "@RequiredArgsConstructor" instead of "AllArgsConstructor" to iclude only final parameters (it's not an issue but a better way). otherwise, i'm cheking the rest ;)

Comment: I think that your bean "AuthService" is loaded before "passwordEncoder", you could check it by adding a breakpoint at this line "return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();". If you see the exception thrown before you get into your breakpoint, then you should to create that bean outside the "SecurityConfig", to test it for example, put it in the Application class (where you put the main method)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @Configuration annotation in your SecurityConfig class

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33793042)